# Try-except error in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a Python script which has a batch command in between,

```
batch_cmd = "batch command"
subprocess.call(batch_cmd)
```

Consider this scenario where I want to repeat running this batch command if it fails. I tried to use try/except in such a way that the batch_cmd has to be repeated in the 'except' part too. That is:

```
try: 
    batch_cmd = "batch command"
    subprocess.call(batch_cmd)

except:
    print "error. retrying"
    subprocess.call(batch_cmd)
```

The exception is not getting caught, however. If the batch command in the try block fails, then it just bypasses the 'except' block and executes the remaining of the script. How can I rewrite the try/except part for this? Or is there any other method other than try/except? I know there have been similar questions on SO but the solutions have not helped me so far.

Comment: Please do not use `except:` ever. If you really want all exceptions, use `except Exception:`. Otherwise things like KeyboardInterrupt will be caught, too, which is almost always not what you want.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Agreed, and btw that page of your playing some nice Swedish music atm! Hammerfall ftw! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an exception in case the called command fails (nonzero exit code), use [`subprocess.check_call(batch_cmd)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) to execute it.

Also use `except subprocess.CalledProcessError:` in this case to avoid catching more exceptions than necessary.

Comment: Adding subprocess.check_call() worked! Thanks a lot :) Accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend it. If anything you should rather set a fixed numbers of re-tries and use a counter to break the loop if it tries too many times. And in case it still fails to execute you `raise` a new exception to prevent the code from continuing.

If you really need to you could do something recursive like this.

```
def ExectuteBatchCommand(batch_cmd)
    try: 
        subprocess.call(batch_cmd)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print "error. retrying"
        ExectuteBatchCommand(batch_cmd)
```

Comment: It was most likely because it wasn't throwing a `CalledProcessError`, if you repalce it with `Exception` or `WindowsError` it should work, at least until you reach an stackoverflow. :p

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.call returns the error code. Place that in a variable and use an if statement to check if it failed.